# How to add Broadcast in Android?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want android to notify me of an app launch by sending a broadcast whenever there is a launch. Where to put the broadcast? I don't want to poll continuously and look for changes in the list of running apps.

Answer (score 2):

Sending a `Broadcast` is as easy as few lines of code. Just pass an `Intent` object with with `sendBroadcast()` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
intent.putExtra("MyData", 1000);
sendBroadcast(intent);﻿
```